# How to download the first 20.04 .iso

Tags: iso

Is there a way for us to download the original **20.04** .iso without the .1 or .2 updates? I see that only the **20.04.2** version is available for downloading.

I want it to use the original kernel, not the HWE one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the link from old-releases subdomain:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

or torrent

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

---

Netboot mini.iso (if needed) is available here:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso

---

Currently there is https://linuxdistros.org/ site with flavor torrents:

- [kubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent](https://linuxdistros.org/torrents/kubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.html)
- [lubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent](https://linuxdistros.org/torrents/lubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.html)
- [ubuntu-budgie-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent](https://linuxdistros.org/torrents/ubuntu-budgie-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.html)
- [ubuntu-mate-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent](https://linuxdistros.org/torrents/ubuntu-mate-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.html)
- [ubuntukylin-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent](https://linuxdistros.org/torrents/ubuntukylin-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.html)
- [ubuntustudio-20.04-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent](https://linuxdistros.org/torrents/ubuntustudio-20.04-dvd-amd64.iso.html)
- [xubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent](https://linuxdistros.org/torrents/xubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso.html)

Comment: Only the **Ubuntu** isos are available on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com. I can't find any other flavors there. I guess I'll have to use the `mini.iso` to install those if needed. Thank you anyway.