# Sorry,there was a problem completing the installaion

Tags: server, 20.04, virtualbox

I am installing **ubuntu server on VM (in Ubuntu)**. However, I tried **Virt-Manager** and **VMbox** both show same error I have tried some solutions on the internet they did not work for me.

Please, help if you can

I have spent 2-3 days on this.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download the first 20.04 .iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320886/how-to-download-the-first-20-04-iso) - try to use Netboot mini.iso instead.

Comment: Without seeing the 'full report' it's impossible to determine why installation fails.  Just as an FYI, it'd be great to see a screenshot of the last bunch of lines on the full report to see where in the process it fails.

Answer (score 0):

also spent all the morning but figured why its so out.

**1st**

you need to set its memory to greater than default

in VB manager do so:

*new, setname , next, memory size 4096, remainings are as default*

**2nd**

*settings, storage, empty, check on 'live cd/dvd`'
click on disk icon
pickup iso you got from ubuntu site
ok*

**3d**

in VB manager go to network
before 'start' go to

*settings->network->adapter1->notattached*
then *start, defaults* - exactly what it suggests

**4th**

it should opt for you reboot , but
before that go to VB manager again and enable

*network, setting its adapter1 to nat*

reboot server

And you are done my friend.

Have installed Ubuntu 20 and 21 this way

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error while installing a new Ubuntu server on Windows hyper-v. All I had to do was uncheck "Set up this disk as an LVM group" when the installer asks about storage. Maybe this helps someone.

Comment: This did not work on proxmox :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and fixed it by assigning a proper file system (NTFS) to the hard drive. You can assign a file system by attaching the hard drive to the working system like Windows OS or Linux. Below are the steps on how to assign a file system to the hard drive from Windows 10.

If your hard drive isn't set up yet, it won't show in File Explorer. To make it usable, you need to do a few things like initializing, creating a new partition, and formatting.

You can tell if a hard drive doesn't have a partition because it won't show in File Explorer, and it'll be unallocated space in Disk Management.

Here are the steps to set up a new hard drive on Windows 10:

Step 1: Click Start.

Step 2: Search for "Create and format hard disk partitions" and open Disk Management.

Step 3: Right-click the "Unknown" and "Not Initialized" hard drive and choose Initialize Disk.

Step 4: Check the disk to initialize and choose the partition style:

MBR for hard drives smaller than 2TB.
GPT for hard drives larger than 2TB.

Step 5: Click OK.

Step 6: Right-click the Unallocated space and choose "New Simple Volume."

Step 7: Follow the prompts:

-> Specify volume size or use the default for the entire hard drive.

-> Choose a drive letter.

-> Select NTFS as the file system.

-> Choose default allocation unit size.

-> Type a name for the storage.

-> Opt for a quick format unless you want a full format, which takes longer.

-> Skip file and folder compression.

Step 8: Click Finish.

Once these steps are done, your new hard drive will be ready to use.

If you encounter issues with Disk Management, you can use the DiskPart command-line tool to fix problems like data corruption.